# Changes are not reflecting even after invalidating cache in cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, caching, amazon-cloudfront, browser-cache

I am using aws cloudfront and s3 bucket to run my vite react project

I did invalidate cache in cloudfront and I do see changes in incognito mode but not on normal browser tab, and also if I did hard refresh on normal tab the changes are appear and then after normal reload they goes.

Did below changes from other stackoverflow answers

- incrementing version of my react app before build. (npm version patch)
- Build config of vite app

```
build: {
    sourcemap: false,
    manifest: true
},
```

- Meta tag added in index.html file

```
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, private">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

I expect browser to store cache but after new changes or cache invalidation it should take new changes over the local browser cached data.

Comment: Invalidating the cache in Cloudfront does not and cannot affect the cached resource in the browser. There's basically no way for the server to invalidate the browser cache, so whatever cache scheme you come up should not depend on that capability.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to return the header:
`Cache-Control: no-cache`.
This should prevent the browser to cache content locally and to fetch this content systematically from the POP.